# BufferedWriter NOT writing to .txt file [JAVA]

Tags: java, client-server, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

**Aim:** The server reads in data from a text file sent by a client. The server stores this data in another text file.

**Problem:** I am able to read in the text file and print it to the console however, when i run my code with the BufferedWriter and open the new textfile after, the file is empty. I am not entirely sure whether i have used the BufferedWriter function incorrectly or if i am missing any key functions out?

**Code:**

```
BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String fromServer;
String fromUser;

while (true) {

        fromUser = stdIn.readLine();

        if (fromUser != null) {

            FileReader file = new FileReader("client-temp.txt");
            BufferedReader tc = new BufferedReader(file);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("datastore.txt"));

            String line;

            while ((line = tc.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] data = line.split(",");
                String sensortype = data[0];
                String date = data[1];
                String time = data[2];
                String reading = data[3];

                String newdata = sensortype + date + time + reading;
                System.out.println(line);

                if (line != null)
                {
                    out.write(line);
                    out.flush();
                }

                System.out.println("Data sent to file");

            }


            System.out.println(EmsClientID + " sending " + fromUser + " to EmsServer");
            out.println(fromUser);
        }
        fromServer = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(EmsClientID + " received " + fromServer + " from EmsServer");
    }
```

Comment: You didn't flush or close the writer...besides, where did you actually ever write to the `bw`?

Comment: i have used out.flush()? @MadProgrammer

Comment: But what is `out`?  All I see is `bw` which is never used...

Comment: @MadProgrammer oh i see, i understand. I have used the wrong names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call `flush` or `close` on the instance of `BufferedWriter`, in fact, you ignore it completely.  Also, you resource management is none existent.  If you open a resource, you should close it.

For example...

```
FileReader file = new FileReader("client-temp.txt");
try (BufferedReader tc = new BufferedReader(file)) {
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("datastore.txt"))) {

        String line;

        while ((line = tc.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] data = line.split(",");
            String sensortype = data[0];
            String date = data[1];
            String time = data[2];
            String reading = data[3];

            String newdata = sensortype + date + time + reading;
            System.out.println(line);

            if (line != null)
            {
                bw.write(line);
                bw.newLine();
            }

            System.out.println("Data sent to file");
        }
    } catch (IOException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

See [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details

(*ps: You can compound the `try-with-resource` statement, opening multiple resources within the same `try (...) {` section, but I wanted to demonstrate the basic concept*)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete. I'm gonna go out on a whim here and assume your problem.

Add

```
out.close();
```

at the end of your code.